# Listing Observer doesn't "see" the update

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have to create a class, which observes a vector and is notified every time something changes in it. My problem is, that my program doesn't react on changing contents of the vector. Could somebody please tell me, where I've made a mistake?

The implementation:

```
    class IObserver
{
public:
    virtual void notify() = 0;
    virtual ~IObserver(){};
};

class ObservableVector
{
    vector<int> ov;
    vector<IObserver*> registered;
public:
    void notifyObserver()
    {
        for (IObserver* el : registered)
        {
            el->notify();
        }
    }
    void add(int n)
    {
        ov.push_back(n);
        notifyObserver();
    }
    void registerObserver(IObserver* obs)
    {
        registered.push_back(obs);
    }
    const vector<int> & items() const
    {
        vector<int> it;
        for (int el : ov)
        {
            it.push_back(el);
        }
        return it;
    }
};

class ListingObserver : public IObserver
{
    ObservableVector & _ov;
public:
    ListingObserver(ObservableVector & ov) : _ov(ov)
    {
        _ov.registerObserver(this);
    }
    void notify()
    {
        vector<int> toNotify;
        toNotify = _ov.items();

        cout << "Elements: " << endl;
        for (int el : toNotify)
        {
            cout << el << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ObservableVector ov;
    ListingObserver lo(ov);
    //MeanObserver mo(ov);
    ov.add(1);
    ov.add(2);
    ov.add(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it did actually react. There was a problem in items function though, because you are returning a reference to a variable that is defined on the local stack of the function. In other words, that variable doesn't exist after the function is over, and thus the variable called toNotify is set to be empty.

Perhaps this is what is causing your error, you can solve it by simply returning ov instead of copying its elements into another variable and returning this variable.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with this function

```
const vector<int> & items() const
{
    vector<int> it;
    for (int el : ov)
    {
        it.push_back(el);
    }
    return it;
}
```

Here you create a local vector `it`, and return reference to it, but in the end of function this object is destroyed. So you return a reference to non-existing object, thus you've got undefined behavior.

To correct your code you could decrale this function as

```
vector<int> items() const
```

and leave its implementations as it is now or made it simply like this

```
const vector<int> & items() const
{
    return ov;
}
```